# how to replace form-group with another in Angular?

Tags: angular, forms

I need to replace the existing Form group to updated FormGroup after a condition

```
dataForm = this.fb.group({
    a: this.fb.control('ndemd', Validators.required),
    b: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
    c: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
    d: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
    e: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
    f: this.fb.control('', Validators.required)
  });
```

Now after this I change the page & save data. When I come back on this page, I want to display saved data into dataForm.

like this->

```
dataForm= savedData;
I am working in Angular 7.
```

how to replace form-group with another?

Comment: you have to save data in service and patch it on init. this.dataForm.patchValue(this.saveService.formData)

Answer (score -2):

Saved data will be as an Object, if that object's keys has the same names of `formGroup`; you can simply call `satValue` function:

```
this.dataForm.setValue(savedValue);
```